# "Hopefully you find this post interesting"

Tags: grammar, tense

I am writing a blog post and at the end of the post, I wanted to say this:

> Hopefully, you find this post interesting

But I don't know here what the correct tense is. Since the sentence is at the end of the post, the reader presumably should have read this blog already. So I was wondering if I should use simple past tense instead, as in:

> Hopefully, you found this post interesting

Answer (score 1):

Either is fine. The first version looks forward from the time at which your wrote the piece; the second looks backward from the time at which the reader reads it. In fact, other tenses are also possible:

> Hopefully, you've found this post interesting. (<-- looking backward)
> Hopefully, you'll find this post interesting. (<-- looking forward)
> Hopefully, you will have found this post interesting. (<-- looking forward and then backward)

The last option would be somewhat uncommmon (as future perfect often is).

Comment: interesting... does the tense affect the tone or any other things?

Comment: @Joji Not in my opinion. I think that all versions are pretty similar in both meaning and tone.